# Some thing wrong with my sharing script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, sharing

Please help me this is the code in which i want to embed the facebook sharing script.

```
<a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
```

this is how i am embedding it

```
 <script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(‘http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=’+encodeURIComponent(u)+’&t=’+encodeURIComponent(t),’sharer’,’toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436′);return false;}</script>
                              <a href="<?php echo'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=';?><?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                                 onclick=”return fbs_click()” target=”_blank”><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
function facebook()
{
window.open("http://facebook.com/sharer.php?app_id=1433580610197489&sdk=joey&u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>","_blank","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=650, height=540");
}

function google()
{
window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>","_blank","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=650, height=540");
}
function twitter()
{
window.open("http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_permalink(); ?>","_blank","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=650, height=540");
}
function linkedin()
{
window.open("http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title='.$title.'","_blank","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=650, height=540");
}
function pinterest()
{
window.open("http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>","_blank","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=650, height=540");
}
</script> 
<ul>
 <li class="social-facebook"><a title="Facebook" onclick="facebook()" ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
 <li class="social-gplus"><a title="Google+" onclick="google()" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
 <li class="social-twitter"><a title="Twitter" onclick="twitter()" ><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
 <li class="social-pinterest"><a title="Pinterest" onclick="pinterest()" ><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
 <li class="social-linkedin"><a title="LinkedIn" onclick="linkedin()" ><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just one problemo With the code .. It keeps sharing the same post which i shared for the first time even if i share some different post whose permalink is different.. any ideas

Comment: Actually if there are ten posts on home page then it always keep sharing the last post on the page –

Comment: something very little is wrong now it generates no link after u=

Comment: add echo : <?php echo curPageURL(); ?>

Comment: can it be the issue site being hosted on sub domain                                                   Because its not working

Comment: i did try it <?php echo curPageURL(); ?> but result is same

Comment: any ways your answer solve this problem . its just little one . i will try to  figure out